# Vim – a shortcut for site-wide search?

Tags: search, vim, performance

My day-to-day work consists of often needing to find HTML classes or CSS selectors of the same name in either HTML or Sass partials.

At present I'm doing this:

`:vimgrep /searchTerm/ **/*.html`

OR:

`:vimgrep /searchTerm/ **/*.scss`

However, this is quite inefficient to type manually each time so I'm looking for a shortcut. I'm new to Vim but having Googled and search SO I'm known the wiser.

Is it possible to create some short cut so all I have to enter is:

`:se searchTerm scss` or `:se searchTerm html` and have it automatically fill in the repeated parts? I'm just using `:se` in that example as it's terse but I suppose it could be whatever.

Or, is there some smarter search tool I should be using? I'm used to Sublime's search which I've always been happy with - it's lightning fast and also presents a list of results you can choose from clicking one takes you directly to the class/selector.

Any pointers/productivity tips here appreciated.

Update: Just found https://github.com/dkprice/vim-easygrep and this looks pretty intuitive. Anything else similar to this I should look at?

Comment: Use ack.vim and ack and put stuff in your ackrc like "--type-set
html=.html" and then type :Ack search --html and you're done. Avoid built in things like vimgrep or args if possible as they're poor substitutes for better tools

Comment: Thanks Andy, that might be the answer although from a cursory look through, there is no search and replace capability - is that correct? Just found https://github.com/dkprice/vim-easygrep and that looks pretty intuitive.

Comment: Correct. I do project wide search and replace so infrequently that I don't care about optimizing it. It's usually too dangerous - your keyword matches things in the wrong places. I always do it by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, let's turn this into a custom command. `:se` won't do, custom commands must start with an uppercase letter, so let's use `:Se`:

```
:command Se vimgrep /searchTerm/ **/*.html
```

This isn't parameterized yet. Let's allow an argument for the search term:

```
:command -nargs=1 Se vimgrep /<args>/ **/*.html
```

Then, default the file extension to the current buffer's; we now need `:execute` to interpolate the value:

```
:command -nargs=1 Se execute 'vimgrep /<args>/ **/*.' . expand('%:e')
```

Passing both pattern and extension as arguments requires that we split the arguments. Vim can pass individual strings by using `<f-args>`; we can make a List out of that by wrapping it with `[` and `]`, and then use indexing to extract the arguments:

```
:command -nargs=+ Se execute 'vimgrep /' . [<f-args>][0] . '/ **/*.' . [<f-args>][1]
```

Voila!

---

Of course, there are several plugins that make searching easier, but as you can see, it's also quite easy to gradually build a custom command for a particular use. `:help :command` has all the information.

Comment: That's absolutely blown my mind! Thanks Ingo – will take me a bit of time to wrap my head around that (and the possibilities) but the step by step is very useful. Was great to see the solution built up.

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly type a little less by shortening `:vimgrep` to `:vim`.

Appending `| cw` to your command opens a list of matches in the quickfix window. That window can be navigated and searched like any other and, most importantly, you can jump to matches in the list *without* the window itself. See `:help quickfix`.

As demonstrated by Ingo, it's not only possible but also highly recommended to write custom commands and mappings to ease common tasks.

This mapping, for example, searches recursively for the word under the cursor in every `*.html` file under the current directory and shows the list of matches, if any, in the quickfix window:

```
:nnoremap <key> :execute "noautocmd vimgrep /" . expand('<cword>') . "/ **/*.html <bar> cwindow"<CR>
```

Note that `:vimgrep` is slightly slower than `:grep` and that you can change the `grepprg` option to use an external tool like Ack or Ag which are both *a lot* faster than `grep`.

Comment: Thanks romainl – only just fully understanding that Vim can be ANYTHING I need it to be (as long as I can figure it all out). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Typing `<c-r><c-w>` will copy the word under the cursor onto the command line. :vimgrep /searchTerm/ **/*.ext can in most cases be shortened to `:vim <c-r><c-w> **/*.ext`. If you don't mind searching all file types then `:vim <c-r><c-w> **` is even shorter(beware of data/binary files). Furthermore, `q:` will open the command-line window which is searchable. Therefore, after you enter your search the first time likely you will be able to `?vim<CR>Wcw` and retain the previously used extensions even if there was more than one.

Because of the availability of these kinds of tools, instead of writing a custom command (which is very easy) I would try to think about the problem a bit more generally and use it as a means to advance your knowledge of vim.

Of course if you're on a system with an external grep program, :gr -R searchTerm . is also pretty dang short.

If you want to have the lowercase :se command you can use this command:

```
"--Redefine command (taken from vim wiki)--
    command! -nargs=+ CommandCabbr call CommandCabbr(<f-args>)
    function! CommandCabbr(abbreviation, expansion)
        execute 'cabbr ' . a:abbreviation . ' <c-r>=getcmdpos() == 1 && getcmdtype() == ":" ? "'
        \. a:expansion . '" : "' . a:abbreviation . '"<CR>'
    endfunction
```

**NOTE**: I didn't write this function, I picked it up online somewhere (but I don't remember where).
Then you can use `:CommandCabbr se Se`. It's basically command line abbreviation that restricts itself to expanding only at the start of the command line (so se doesn't expand as a command argument or something).

In any case, I tend to not write new commands unless I feel they solve a general task because writing specific commands for every small task messes with your vim fu since keeps you from finding more general solutions. The particular problem here is how to do a structured search of a program and the general solution is really getting css/scss support for ctags. Then you can use g_CTRL-] and a number.